# Angular HttpHeaders responseType: 'text' . giving 'Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'json'"

Tags: angular, http-headers, angular-httpclient

Angular HttpHeaders responseType: 'text' . giving `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'json'`. error.  I know the response is not JSON.  I do not understand how to change the type? I want to take that text (HTML) and parse it with a regex after.

Code

```
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        accept: '*/*',
        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      }),
      responseType: 'text',
    };
    post = this.httpClient.post(destinationUrl, httpBody, httpOptions);

    post.subscribe(
      (res) => {
        console.log(res)
      },
      (error) => {
        console.error('download error:', error)
      },
      () => {
        console.log('Completed')
      },
    );
```

Error from console
[image]

As you can see, the response type is text.  Because of something I don't understand, I cannot make it accept text, as it is waiting for json...

Comment: try adding `observe: 'response' ` right after `responseType: 'text',` in your httpOptions, and do a console.log on response.

Comment: which version of angular are you using?

Comment: version 7.2.0...

Comment: as for `observe: response`, it . errors out before i . can do a  console.log

Comment: post = this.httpClient.post(destinationUrl, httpBody, httpOptions);
    post.subscribe(
      (response) => {
         console.log(response);
         return response;
    }, (err) => {
         throw err;

Comment: I have created a small demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hhjkwk let me know if it helps

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I solved this issue making HTTPOptions as an Object

```
let HTTPOptions:Object = {

        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }),
        responseType: 'text'
     }
    return this.http.post<any>(url, body,  HTTPOptions ).pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError)
    );
```

Comment: What's the difference? Why does this work?

Answer (score 1):

According to [official angular documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#post)

> Overload #3 Constructs a POST request that interprets the body as a
>   text string and returns the response as a string value.
>
> post(url: string, body: any, options: { headers?: HttpHeaders | {
>   [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?:
>   HttpParams | { [param: string]: string | string[]; }; reportProgress?:
>   boolean; responseType: "text"; withCredentials?: boolean; }):
>   Observable Parameters  url    string   The endpoint URL.
>
> body any  The content to replace with.
>
> options  object   HTTP options
>
> Returns Observable: An Observable of the response, with a
>   response body of type string.

By looking at documentation, we can do something like this. The response (inside body) is string:

```
clickMe() {
    this.httpClient.post(
      `https://reqres.in/api/users`,
      {
        name: "paul rudd",
        movies: ["I Love You Man", "Role Models"],
      },
      {
        observe: 'response',
        responseType: 'text',
      }
    ).subscribe(x => console.log('x: ', x.body))
  }
```

[Stackblitz example for code above](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hhjkwk)

Comment: Get same issue. its like the subscribe function doesnt care about the arguments, and goes right to failing :(

Comment: You can also do `observe: 'body',` to get just textual body of the response, without the rest of the Response object.

Also, I'm on Angular 14, and for some reason it would not accept the HttpOptions, unless I typed it as `unknown`. This appears to be a bug with the typings, though, because HttpClient.post() code clearly offers the `observe: 'body', responseType: 'text'` combination.